# In an HTTP Handler, is it acceptable to return 304 when you know the content won't change?

Tags: asp.net, caching, httphandler

I have an HTTP Handler set up which accepts a GUID parameter and returns the image from the file system.

This image will not ever change; the backend program will generate a new GUID if it does. As such, I want the image to always be cached.

Is the correct way to do this to set a status code of 304 (not modified) from the HTTP Handler?

Comment: please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109768/how-to-use-output-caching-on-ashx-handler and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775448/asp-net-cache-setcacheabilityhttpcacheability-public-not-setting-header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you setting proper HTTP response headers in order to indicate to the clients that the contents will not change and could be cached:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    var cache = context.Response.Cache;
    cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
    cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.Add(CACHE_DURATION));
    cache.SetMaxAge(CACHE_DURATION);
    cache.AppendCacheExtension("must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");

    byte[] buffer = ...
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

Comment: I have Implemented the code but i still get status as 200 (instead of 304) in browser for my httphandler. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. However, you should return a `HTTP/304` only if the request is **conditional request**. If you know the image with that URL never changes, you can set a very long expiry date (1 year is the max according to the specs).

BTW, [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) is quite easy to read -- I suggest to take look there, for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Also in addition to @Darin's response, have you come across [ETags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag)?  These are one of the common way of implementing caching like you propose.  The first time the browser requests the image you won't have an ETag so you know to serve up the image.  The next time a request is made it will provide the ETag - which you can then use to see whether to return a 304 or the image itself.  In your example you would only be checking for the presence of an ETag or not.

With your proposed solution what would concern me is how do you identify the first request from subsequent requests (and from more than one client)